# Suppress My Files app pop up on USB Card mount

Tags: android, usb, android-sdcard, mount

I'm developing app for Samsung smartphones accessory, that incorporating Mass Storage Device. On device connection I've able to get necessary events and handle it.

But when Mass Storage mounted My Files app is open (I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9500). For example files on my device can be encrypted, so My Files app is completely useless in this case.

Is there any way to suppress opening My Files app on card mount? 
Is app uses some intent, which I can register intent filter, so user can choose which application to open?

Comment: I have an app that uses Samsung Tablets exclusively and have yet to have any luck with this issue as well. I have an intent, but even if my app opens up first, My Files STILL appears afterwards...

Comment: @Steven_BDawg, probably because My Files not using intent, but just open activity on mount card broadcast. Will be great if some of insiders can confirm (or decline) this assumption.